# Как перехватить закрытие (крестиком) дочернего окна tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *


class MainWindow(Tk):  # класс - Главного Окно  ####################################################################
    # (Дочернее-Окно)
    CHILD = None

    def __init__(self, width, height, title='MyWindow', resizable=(False, False), icon=None):
        super().__init__()

        # (Главное-Окно)
        self.title(title)
        self.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+250+200')
        self.resizable(resizable[0], resizable[1])
        if icon is not None:
            self.iconbitmap(icon)

        # (Клавиша)
        self.btn = Button(self, text='Создать Дочернее Окно', command=self.btn_on_pressed)

    def run(self):  # запуск Главного-Окна
        self.draw_widgets()
        self.mainloop()

    def draw_widgets(self):  # вывод в Главное-Окно всех виджетов
        self.btn.pack()

    def create_child(self, width, height, title='Child', resizable=(False, False), icon=None):  # создание Дочернего-Окна
        if MainWindow.CHILD is not None:  # удаление предыдущего экземпляра Дочернего-Окна
            self.delete_child()
            MainWindow.CHILD = None

        MainWindow.CHILD = ChildWindow(self, width, height, title, resizable, icon)  # создание нового Дочернего-Окна

    @classmethod
    def delete_child(cls):  # уничтожение Дочернего Окна
        cls.CHILD.child_root.destroy()

    def btn_on_pressed(self):
        self.create_child(300, 300, 'Child', (False, False))


class ChildWindow:  # класс - Дочернее-Окно  #######################################################################

    def __init__(self, master, width, height, title='Child', resizable=(False, False), icon=None):
        # (Главное Окно)
        self.master = master

        # (Дочернее-Окно)
        self.child_root = Toplevel(master)
        self.child_root.title(f'{title}')
        self.child_root.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+800+200')
        self.child_root.resizable(resizable[0], resizable[1])
        if icon is not None:
            self.child_root.iconbitmap(icon)


# обращение:
if __name__ == '__main__':  # ДЛЯ ТЕСТИРОВАНИЯ (в этом же Модуле)
    main_win = MainWindow(300, 200, 'Main Window')  # создание Главного-Окна
    main_win.run()  # запуск Главного-Окна
```

- Здравствуйте все! Доброго всем времени суток! Мой вопрос понятен из самого заголовка.
  Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод `protocol`:

```
def create_child(self, width, height, title='Child', resizable=(False, False), icon=None):  # создание Дочернего-Окна
    if MainWindow.CHILD is not None:  # удаление предыдущего экземпляра Дочернего-Окна
        self.delete_child()
        MainWindow.CHILD = None

    MainWindow.CHILD = ChildWindow(self, width, height, title, resizable, icon)  # создание нового Дочернего-Окна
    MainWindow.CHILD.child_root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.func) # перехватили

def func(self): # функция перехвата
    print('child root closing function.')
```

Comment: - Спасибо n1trOxs! Еще не пользовался методом - protocol(). Теперь буду знать.